# how to wrap a series of li into one div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html code:

```
<ul>
 <li id="a1">content</li>
 <li id="a2">content</li>
 <li id="a3">content</li>
 <li id="a4">content</li>
 <li id="a5">content</li>
 <li id="a6">content</li>
 <li id="a7">content</li>
</ul>
```

I want to use jquery to wrap these li tags into one div, same as:

```
<ul>
 <div id="list1">
  <li id="a1">content</li>
  <li id="a2">content</li>
  <li id="a3">content</li>
  <li id="a4">content</li>
  <li id="a5">content</li>
 </div>
 <div id="list2">
  <li id="a6">content</li>
  <li id="a7">content</li>
 </div>
</ul>
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you!

EDIT: sorry for the confusion, to clarify my question: I have a series of li tags in one ul, i want to wrap some of them into one div (for example, wrap a1 to a5 in one div, a6 to a7 in one div). What i know for sure is that the li tags that I want to wrap have consecutive numbers as their ids.

EDIT2: I realized that it's not valid to have divs inside a ul. The reason I'm asking this question is that I want to use jquery ui tabs to break the ul into two tabs, one having li a1 to a5 in it, a6 and a7 in the other tab. I cannot modify the html code so I wanted to know how to do this using jquery

Comment: You should be wrapping it in UL, not DIV

Comment: That's invalid HTML!  You can't have an li inside a div like that.

Comment: A DIV in between UL and LI is not proper HTML.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: You can't wrap li's in divs.  Why do you want to wrap them?  Maybe wrap 'em in another ul?

Comment: what is the reason for wrapping li's into div? Are you going to hide/show the divs?

Comment: Because I want to use jquery ui tabs to break the ul into two tabs, one having li a1 to a5 in it, a6 and a7 in the other tab. I cannot modify the html code so I wanted to know how to do this using jquery

Comment: @AlanHan: That's not how jQuery UI tabs works.  Each li is a tab.  In your case, there are 7 tabs.  Do you want 2 main tabs, and then each of those tabs to have sub tabs?

Comment: @Rocket Yes that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: @AlanHan: Ok.  That will take a bit of work to do.

Comment: @Rocket Yea I guess I have to try something else, thanks anyways!

Comment: @AlanHan: Hold up, I think I can still help ya.  Give me a sec to make a new answer.

Comment: @AlanHan: How's this: http://jsfiddle.net/cCjbC/1/ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, you want to split these 7 tabs into two tabs, each with sub tabs.  You said you're using jQuery UI tabs.

jQuery UI tabs uses the following layout:

```
<div id="tabs">
   <!-- These are the tabs -->
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#tab-A">Tab A</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-B">Tab B</a></li>
   </ul>
   <!-- This is your tab content -->
   <div id="tab-A">
     This is tab A
   </div>
   <div id="tab-B">
     This is tab B
   </div>
</div>
```

Running `$('#tabs').tabs()` will convert this into a two-tabbed layout.  You just need to convert your HTML to look like this, and then it'll work.  And then inside each tab, just have another UL/div setup to add inner-tabs.

Here is how you can do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/cCjbC/1/

It makes 2 outer tabs, then takes your ul, splits it and then adds those as inner tabs.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following code:

```
$("ul")
    .prop("id","list1")
    .after("<ul id='list2'/>");

$("#a6")
    .nextAll()
    .andSelf()
    .appendTo("#list2");
```

And it will turn your single `<ul>` into two `<ul>`'s like so:

```
<ul id="list1">
  <li id="a1">content</li>
  <li id="a2">content</li>
  <li id="a3">content</li>
  <li id="a4">content</li>
  <li id="a5">content</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
  <li id="a6">content</li>
  <li id="a7">content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note: In order to maintain events and other properties of the `ul`, it my be of interest to [`.clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it and remove the clone's children.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking here, but why not add UL tags and wrap that with your DIV?

```
<div id="list">
<ul>
<li id="a1">content</li>
<li id="a2">content</li>
<li id="a3">content</li>
<li id="a4">content</li>
<li id="a5">content</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: He's asking how to add the tags using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've edited my question, hope it clarifies what I'm looking for